# PHP STR_TO_DATE() Function not posting

Tags: php, mysql, html, post

I'm trying to insert dates using the STR_TO_DATE() function. It keeps failing for some reason. Can anyone help? Thanks

HTML:

```
   <form action="config.php" method="POST">
Total Sales : <br><input type="text" id="total" name="total"><br>
Company Name : <br><input type="text" id="company" name="company"><br>
Sales Type : <br><input type="text" id="type" name="type"><br>
Sales Date : <br><input type="date" id="saledate" name="saledate"><br>
Date Entered : <br><input type="date" id="dateenter" name="dateenter"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");

$Total = $_POST['total'];
$Company = $_POST['company'];
$Type = $_POST['type'];
$Saledate = $_POST['saledate'];
$Dateentered = $_POST['dateenter'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO htgsales (SaleAmount,Company,SalesType,SalesDate,DateEntered) VALUES ('$Total','$Company','$Type',STR_TO_DATE('$Saledate', '%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('$Dateentered', '%m/%d/%Y'))";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo 'Insert Failed';
}
else
{
echo 'Success';
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: What are the values of `$Saledate` and `$Dateentered`? Are you sure they match the format you're using?

Comment: @Barmar the format is 6/23/2016

Comment: Are you getting an error from the query? You should print `mysqli_error($con)` instead of just `Insert failed`, so you see the reason fior the error.

Comment: @Barmar okay I did that and its not giving any errors

Comment: Your question said that it's failing. What exactly is it doing wrong?

Comment: @Barmar the SQL table contains an ID auto integer. Should I include that in the php code? I didn't think that that'd be the problem.

Comment: No, you don't need to include it. Leaving it out will make it increment automatically.

Comment: @Barmar its not actually posting to the table. The $sql doesn't execute for some reason

Comment: I don't see how that can happen. If it prints `Success`, the query executed successfully, and that means it inserted something.

Comment: @Barmar its not printing `success` it keeps printing `insert failed`

Comment: Try executing your query directly in SQL Server using phpmyadmin or some other tool, to verify your query.

Comment: Change it to `echo 'Insert failed: ' . mysqli_error($con);` and tell the reason for the failure.

Comment: @Barmar @DBA I got it working I had to change the input types from `date` to `text` and added `if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure why you needed to do that. How does it change the value of the `$_POST` values?

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL documentation:

> This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

What's the value of the post parameters you get for the dates? Do they match the format you're passing to the function? Try doing a var_dump of $_POST and paste the values, so we can check if there's something wrong.

Comment: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's',STR_TO_DATE('6/21/16', '%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('6/21/16', '%m/%d/%Y'))' at line 1`

Comment: Can you paste the whole sql string?